# Override List (Of).Add Behaviour

Tags: vb.net, generics

I hava a class with this public property

```
Private _tickets As List(Of Ticket)
Public Property Ticekts() As List(Of Ticket)
    Get
        Return _tickets
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Ticket))
        _tickets = value
    End Set
End Property
```

When I call the add method, I have to perform some logic BEFORE add the ticket.

The logic is not an important topic, but I eventually have to remove some ticket before ADD the new one.

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to _remove_ when calling Add? Trying to confuse users of your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to derive your own collection as follows:

C# version:

```
public class MyList<T> : Collection<T>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        // your checks here
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

`List<T>` doesn't have virtual methods so you aren't able to override Add.  `Collection<T>` has virtual InsertItem, SetItem, RemoveItem and ClearItems.

VB.NET version:

```
Public Class List(Of T) 
    Inherits Collection(Of T)

    Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem( index As Integer, item As T )
        'your checks here
        MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is a nice solution, but this topic talks about VB.NET

Comment: @Angelodev - Not off topic, but wrong .NET language. Phil - if the question is in VB.NET, you should have a VB.NET answer (having an _extra_ C# example is a bonus, but the OP wasn't asking for C#).

Comment: I dont understand why people are downvoting when not needed. I really ask the person who dowvoted, why?! you can improve the answer by adding comments, and I am sure the owner of the answer will update the answer accordingly

Comment: @AnarchistGeek - Your definition of "not needed" is not shared by the downvoter, apparently. I believe the comments address why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: @Angelodev - Added VB.Net version.  I could have answered in pseudo-code, it's the method that's important, not the language.

Comment: I don not think that "the method that's important, not the language".

Comment: Phil - for some people the language _is_ important. Not everyone can mentally translate between languages, in particular if they are just starting to program.

Comment: @Oded what I am saying is that language difference(obviously .net languages I am talking about) should not be a reason for downvoting. IMO, answer should be downvoted if it is a wrong answer or unrelated answer. Otherwise, it should be improved by comments. I hope I am clear enough now.

Comment: @AnarchistGeek - I understood what you said. I responded by explaining that not everyone thinks like you. I agree that this did not need to be downvoted, but someone else thought it should.

Comment: Ok, in future I will endeavour to provide a VB.NET solution to a VB.NET question :-)